# how to remove punctuation and irrelevant letters in a string?

Tags: string

I want to write a program that will take a string(max length 1000) as input. The words have spaces in between. For output, each of the words will be in a separate line, no punctuation would be printed and the 1st letter of each word would be capital.

In my code, the problem is it's printing something else in case of punctuations and sometimes some extra letters are printed after the last word. How to solve this? Or, Can I somehow decrease the index number of each element in the string after getting any punctuation?

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[1000], b[1000];
    int i;

    printf("enter a line : ");
    gets(a);

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        if(a[i] == ' '){
            b[i] = '\n';
        }
        if(a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z')
        b[i] = a[i];
    }

    b[0] = a[0] + 'A' - 'a';

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    if(a[i] == ' ' && a[i+1] >= 'a' && a[i+1] <= 'z'){
            b[i+1] = a[i+1] - ('a' - 'A');
         }
     }

    printf("%s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some solution for this , there was an problem with if condition , instead of else if condition I just used else ,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   char a[1000], b[1000];
    int i;

    printf("enter a line : ");
    gets(a);

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        if(a[i] == ' '){
            b[i] = '\n';
        }
       else{
        b[i] = a[i]; //i made changes here
       }
    }

    b[0] = a[0] + 'A' - 'a';

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    if(a[i] == ' ' && a[i+1] >= 'a' && a[i+1] <= 'z'){
            b[i+1] = a[i+1] - ('a' - 'A');
         }
     }

    printf("%s", b);

    return 0;


}
```

output:

```
enter a line : A paragraph is a self-contained unit of discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea. A paragraph consists of three or more sentences. Though not required by the syntax of any language, paragraphs are usually an expected part of formal writing, used to organize longer prose. 
!
Paragraph
Is
A
Self-contained
Unit
Of
Discourse
In
Writing
Dealing
With
A
Particular
Point
Or
Idea.
A
Paragraph
Consists
Of
Three
Or
More
Sentences.
Though
Not
Required
By
The
Syntax
Of
Any
Language,
Paragraphs
Are
Usually
An
Expected
Part
Of
Formal
Writing,
Used
To
Organize
Longer
Prose.
```

I can find some bugs please carrot it and it will so smooth as u wish.
hope u got an answer

Comment: i used this condition a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z' because i don't want to print the punctuations. In your code, the punctuations are not cancelling.

Comment: there is function called ``` ispunct```  in c . try it out it may help you

Answer (score 0):

hello I guess you got solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
   char a[1000], b[1000];
    int i;

    printf("enter a line : ");
    gets(a);

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        if(a[i] == ' '){
            b[i] = '\n';
        }
       else{
        b[i] = a[i]; //i made changes here
       }
    }


char ch="";
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
   if(ispunct(b[i]) != 0){
       b[i]=ch;
      
   }
     }

    printf("%s", b);

    return 0;


}
```

output

```
enter a line : A paragraph is a self-contained unit of discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea. A paragraph consists of three or more sentences. Though not required by the syntax of any language, paragraphs are usually an expected part of formal writing, used to organize longer prose. 
A
paragraph
is
a
selfcontained
unit
of
discourse
in
writing
dealing
with
a
particular
point
or
idea
A
paragraph
consists
of
three
or
more
sentences
Though
not
required
by
the
syntax
of
any
language
paragraphs
are
usually
an
expected
part
of
formal
writing
used
to
organize
longer
prose
```

Comment: okay, but idk why it's printing a right arrow in my computer whenever it's finding a punctualtion.

Comment: please show the output (how it look like?). if you found some solution with the help of my work please "check right" so that it helps to build my profile

Comment: but is there any way to do it without the function ispunct?

Comment: i have added the code with output in the next ans. please check it

Comment: ok let me try to solve it

Comment: if((b[i] >= 'a' && b[i] <= 'z') || (b[i] >= 'A' && b[i] <= 'Z')){}

this logic u must use inside for loop try it out .

Comment: it's already inside in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

why is there a right arrow instead of cancelling the punctuations? Also, is there any other way to cancel punctuations without using the function ispunct?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    
    int main()
     {
       char a[1000], b[1000];
        int i;
    
        printf("enter a line : ");
        gets(a);
    
        for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            if(a[i] == ' '){
                b[i] = '\n';
            }
            else{
            b[i] = a[i];
           }
        }
    
        b[0] = a[0] + 'A' - 'a';
    
        for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        if(a[i] == ' ' && a[i+1] >= 'a' && a[i+1] <= 'z'){
                b[i+1] = a[i+1] - ('a' - 'A');
             }
         }
    
    
       char ch="";
        for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
       if(ispunct(b[i]) != 0){
           b[i]=ch;
    
       }
         }
    
         printf("%s", b);
    
        return 0;
    
    
    }
```

output:

[image: printing right arrow instead of cancelling punctuation]